# How to write to holding registers in pymodbus?

Tags: pymodbus

I want to write to the holding registers an actuator of mine has, but I've only recently started using pymodbus and I'm a little uncertain about some of its commands. As far as I've understand the primary write command looks like this:

write_register(address, value, **kwargs)

But I'm uncertain about how I "define" which kind of register I write too. Unlike other modbus libraries I've used, in pymodbus I can't define which kind of register I write too. As far as I understand of modbus there's coils, input registers and holding registers. I've read that you can't write to input registers, but how can I be certain I write to holding registers? If I write 1 in address in the write_register will that always be a holding register with that address?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know a little bit more about your actuator. Do you have a datasheet about it? If yes, you need to find a map registers where all the addresses are given for registers where the actuator's information are stored. Here an example where you can find this kind of registers map : [SIMEAS Pxxx Com-Modbus Datasheet](http://sm-industry.ru/titan_img/ecatalog/SIMEAS_Pxxx_Com_Modbus_A4_EN.pdf).

Be careful, sometimes you need to add or subtrace 1 to your register address because the guys who implement this did in this way. Read your datasheet carefully.

So if you need to write something in a particular register, you need the correct address of the register, the value you want to write in the correct format, and the client of the library ModbusClient.

You should have something like this :

```
client = ModbusClient(host='YOUR_IP_ADRESS', port=xxx)
client.connect()
client.write_register(REGISTER_ADRESS, PAYLOAD, UNIT)
```

Hope this will help a little. You can also go further by reading  [the Pymodbus documentation](http://riptideio.github.io/pymodbus/).

Comment: Prior to the edit by another user, the display text for your first link displayed a significantly different URL (different domain, etc.) than where the link actually went. While that could easily have just been a mistake, it's often an indicator of deception. I'd recommend making sure that if a link is displaying a URL, then that the link actually link to the URL which is displayed.

Comment: Hi Makyen, I'm not sure to understand what you say. You don't saw a pdf when you opened the link ?

Comment: I never opened the link. The issue was that the text displayed in your answer here for the link to the PDF was showing one URL (what people would see) while the link actually targeted a different URL (where they would have actually been taken if they clicked on the link). You can see the issue in [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60604066/1) or [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60604066/2).

Comment: Ok I see but I don't understand why because I didn't write the text showed in the revisions. I just put the full URL first and after a more friendly text instead of the URL. I dont know why the URL changed. Thanks for notice.